# Handling ambiguous tags

Tags: discussion, tags

How should we handle ambiguous tags?  Here are a couple examples:

[water](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water) could be referring to:

- Sinks
- Water supply
- Rain
- Flooding

[vent](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vent) or [exhaust-vent](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exhaust-vent) could be referring to:

- Dryer vent
- Bathroom vent
- Gas vent
- Plumbing vent (see also [dwv](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwv))

My own thoughts for water are that we have tags for plumbing already, and we could designate water to only be non-plumbing related (rain/flooding).  But for vent, I think it makes sense to retag any questions with this to a more specific type of vent tag and possibly eliminate the original tag.

Edit: since we have [dwv](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwv) for plumbing vents, and I feel that [exhaust-vent](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exhaust-vent) most frequently refers to a bathroom vent, that would leave us with only dryer vents and gas vents.  Is there a proper term for a gas (combustion) vent?

If we do decide to reorganize, should any frequently mis-used tags include references in their wiki to other tags to consider?

Comment: See also: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/221/22 and the various other posts linked there.

Comment: note that you can enter tags as [tag:vent] to have them appear as tags

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I went looking for that syntax when I made the hvac post and forgot to clean this up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be careful of adding compound tags; you can always specify you want two tags like so:

- https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vent+bathroom
- https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vent+plumbing
- https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water+rain

Probably the best thing to do here is make sure questions are tagged appropriately.

Comment: Wouldn't that turn "vent" into a meta tag that is only useful in the context of a second tag?

Comment: @B Mitch: meta tags attempt to describe the post itself(such as [tips-and-tricks] or [homework]) but don't describe the content of the post. On rpg.se we have had similar discussions and as [@SevenSidedDie said](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/411/what-are-the-meta-tags#comment-1105): _I think the vagueness sort of "different things" is what we're avoiding. Tags that are ambiguous —that is, have different but well-defined meanings depending on the context—aren't a problem._

Comment: @yhw42, thanks for that, meta is the wrong term here.  I think the problem I'm trying to solve is "how do I get a list of questions about a bathroom exhaust vent?"  Someone can correctly tag the plumbing vent for their toilet and exhaust fan with the same vent+bathroom combo and it means completely different things.